# How to prevent screen orientation changeing returning from camera intent (SGS3)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-orientation, orientation-changes

In my App I call a second Activity with a ImgButton which calls the camera intent on onClick(). After i took a photo, back in my activity i show an AlertDialog Box where the user can choose to take a further photo or not. In my manifest i locked the orientation of the 2nd Activity to to portrait, because if i rotate the device the AlertBox dissapears:

```
<activity android:name="SecondActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

In my Mannifest i also added:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

and for fullscreen mode

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

If i take a photo and close the camera intent from portrait mode (without rotating the device) there is a problem with 2 different devices:

HTC Desire: all works fine, i save the application states and restore them if i return from the camera to my activity :D

Galaxy S3*: the camera on the sgs3 seems running default in landscape mode? so if u return to my activity the displayed content of my activity is for the blink of an eye in landscape mode and returns emediatly to portrait mode. BUT the AlertDialog is shown BEFORE the orientation changes so the AlertDialog dissappears before the undesired rotation (so i only see the AlertBox for 0,1 second in landscape mode before it dissapears and the rotation switches back to portrait mode )...

If i end the camera intent from landscape mode, doesnt matter on which device, the problem is the same as on the sgs3*.

How can I prevent this screen rotation after I return into my Activity from the Camera? Can i simply show the AlertBox after this undesired orientation changing? If so how can i do this? Or are ther other workarounds?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english ... xD

Comment: it's pretty late, but have you found a solution? I'm encountering the same problem now with the sgs4..

Comment: @Katharina if the answer beneath does not solve your problem I have no other idea

Comment: ok thank you! I'll give it another try

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem on my own: I just put the

> AlertDialog[...].show();

into the `onResume()` Activity, so if I return from the camera intent to my activity, the AlertDialog rotate with the screen instead of disappearing.

This causes an Error from `WindowManager`

> "[package name] leaked window ..."

but finally it worked as i want and the app does not crash ...

Not sure if this is the best and right solution but it works.